# How can I make this quick sort implementation work?

Tags: python, slice, quicksort

I'm a C++ developer and new to Python. I want to implement quick sort in python, here is my code:

```
from typing import Sequence, MutableSequence

def find_if(list: Sequence, predicate):
    """Find first element of the list which predicate return true"""
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if predicate(list[i]):
            return i
    return None

def find_if_not(list: Sequence, predicate):
    return find_if(list, lambda x : not predicate(x))

def partition(list: MutableSequence, predicate):
    """Reorder elements in list in such away that all element which the predicate
    return `true` precede the elements for which predicate returns false. Return
    value is index of the first element in the second group"""
    first = find_if_not(list, predicate)
    if first == None:
        return first

    for i in range(first+1, len(list)):
        if predicate(list[i]):
            list[i], list[first] = list[first], list[i]
            first = first + 1

    return first

def quick_sort(list: MutableSequence, key = lambda x : x):
    if len(list) <= 1:
        return

    pivot = list[0]
    last1 = partition(list, lambda x : x < pivot)
    first2 = partition(list[last1:], lambda  x : x == pivot)

    quick_sort(list[0:last1])
    if first2:
        quick_sort(list[first2:])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arr = [6, 4, 7, 2, 8, 1, 3, 5, 2, 10, 13, 124, 1, 7]
    result = sorted(arr)
    quick_sort(arr)
    print("My sorted array: ", arr)
    print("Corrected result: ", result)
```

The result is incorrect. I think the problem is `list[0:last1]` and `list[first2:]` make a copy instead of refer to elements in list. How can I make this work? (I don't want to put index range as parameter of `quick_sort` or use non-recursive algorithm.)

Comment: FYI - You should consider accepting answers to all (any) of your previous questions, the least effort possible to thank the people that are helping you..

Comment: Yes, slicing effectively makes copies. Unfortunately Python doesn't have pointers, so you will probably have to pass the list and indices as arguments even if you don't want to. The list will be passed something like a C++ reference, so it's fairly light-weight to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct - *list slicing*, as it's called in python, returns a copy of the original list at the original slice. The simplest solution as far as quicksort goes, is to simply use list concatenation. Instead of returning `None` from quicksort, return the sorted list. Then, concatenate the left list and the right list with the pivot in between them:

```
def quick_sort(list: MutableSequence, key = lambda x : x):
    if len(list) <= 1:
        return list

    ...

    return quick_sort(list[:last1]) + [pivot] + quick_sort(list[first2:])
```

Note that `quick_sort` will return an empty list when provided an empty list, so there's no need for the `if` statement in this case. This is probably the approach you're going to want to take when *using* quicksort as well - many of python's string operations and list operations are non-mutative, and `my_list = quick_sort(my_list)` is just as clear as `my_list.sort()`, besides being able to create a sorted copy of the list without needing to change the list.

Comment: Thank for your help. There might be more than one `pivot` value. It could be better if `[pivot]` is replaced by `list[last1:first2]`.

Comment: That is absolutely a replacement you can make.